# AutoLinking not working on XCode 5.1.1 or 6.1

Tags: llvm, xcode6.1, osx-yosemite

I have an *existing* app (XCode 5.1.1 and iOS 7) that uses AVFoundation.framework. I do NOT have a #import for AVFoundation.framework, and the app builds and runs correctly.

I started another *new* project (XCode 6.1, iOS 8.1) using basic parts of the above app; I have everything set as in the above working app, but the new one will not find the frameworks as needed.

[image]

Anybody have any ideas why this is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... you must NOT have any value in both *Framework Search paths* and *Library Search paths*.  It now works.